# Capturing a kernel dump from a CPU soft lockup at boot?

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel, upstart

I am SAN Booting an Ubuntu server and have configured the 14.04.2 client to the best of my ability according to: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/CrashdumpRecipe

It seems like the article works fine for crashes once the kernel is fully loaded, as I can perform the test using `echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger`.  This creates a kernel dump in /var/crash as expected.

However, a dump is not performed at all when I experience the soft lockup during bootup - any tips here?

I have run `echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/softlockup_panic` to hopefully capture the lockups.

As you can see from the below `dmesg` output, I am hitting these often during a single boot:

```
[   36.473727] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#14 stuck for 22s! [init:1]
[   64.476017] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#14 stuck for 23s! [init:1]
[   96.458232] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#14 stuck for 22s! [init:1]
[  124.470671] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#14 stuck for 22s! [init:1]
[  152.486400] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#14 stuck for 23s! [init:1]
[  180.521244] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#14 stuck for 23s! [init:1]
[  208.549108] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#14 stuck for 23s! [init:1]
[  236.540146] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#14 stuck for 23s! [init:1]
[  276.488262] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#14 stuck for 22s! [init:1]
[  304.456052] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#14 stuck for 22s! [init:1]
[  332.505087] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#14 stuck for 22s! [init:1]
```